# Strange Behavior of SELECT CASE statement when using CASE [String]

Tags: .net, vb.net

[UPDATED WITH THE REAL CODE SO PROBLEM IS REPRODUCIBLE]
I have the following statement:

```
<Test()>
Public Sub SelectCaseTest()
    Dim foo As String = "AccrualAmount"
    Dim result As Boolean = False

    Select Case foo
        Case "AccrualAmount"
            result = True
    End Select
    Assert.IsTrue(result)
End Sub
```

Got this:

```
  Expected: True
  But was:  False
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Framework.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition)
```

Seems pretty simple and straightforward. For some reason, it doesn't step into the select case. If I do foo.Equals("AccrualAmount") in the debugger with that problem case then it returns true. What happens under the hood when VB.NET evaluates the "case "AccrualAmount" " statement? Why does it not agree with the result of the .Equals evaluation?

Comment: we can help you if you provide us, more and real code.

Comment: I'd love to provide more code but the code base is huge and I am looking for maybe pointers on what I should pay attention to. One thing I am going to look for is "Option Compare". But I don't understand why .Equals() returns the correct answer but select case ... doesn't. Any ideas there?

Comment: @Denis you don't need to paste the entire code base. Just enough for us to reproduce it. As I've pointed out below, your example code does not fail.

Comment: Seems like I can now reproduce this in a unit test (updated the question)

Comment: Again, this unit test passes with true. There must be another `Case` that is short-circuiting this?

Comment: Strange, this unit test fails for me. Maybe it is some project setting?

Comment: Am making a little headway, now it says "the character encoding of this file has changed" in VS when I mess around with the string. Then looking at Notepad+/TextPad I see the encoding as "ANSI" on this file where I am messing around with the Unit Test. All other files look like UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking through all the "Option Compare" settings, trying to rewrite this in different ways, etc. I had to copy the unit test somewhere so I temporarily put it into Notepad++. Saw this:

[image]

Holy crap, couldn't believe my luck! Love the US symbol at the end of the "case" statement. So lesson to be learned here is to stick your code from VS to Notepad++ if you see something weird like this. Now it makes sense. Somebody must have copied/pasted the case value from somewhere. Looks like US is hex value F1. Now I just need to figure out where this was copied/pasted from so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Anytime anything is being copied and pasted, it should go through plain, old Notepad.exe to remove possible formatting and unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on with your code that just isn't shown here. I assume this `Select...Case` statement is inside a `Function` or `Sub`? Because this works:

`.aspx` page:

```
<p runat="server" id="poutput"></p>
```

`.aspx.vb` code-behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Dim foo As String = example()
        poutput.InnerText = foo
    End If
End Sub

Protected Function example() As String
    Dim SomeVar As String
    SomeVar = "hello"
    Select Case SomeVar
        Case "hello"
            Return "got it"
    End Select
    Return "no match"
End Function
```

Is there more that you can show to help us reproduce your error?

Comment: Do you think it uses .equals? Or what does it use to check equality?

Comment: [Here is the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx) that basically says "it depends"...`The setting of Option Compare can affect string comparisons. Under Option Compare Text, the strings "Apples" and "apples" compare as equal, but under Option Compare Binary, they do not.` But I'm guessing there is something else that you haven't shown.

Comment: What do you think about my previous question?